# Hibernate Check if DB exists

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm creating a db using an initial.sql

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">qet</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/database/initial.sql</property>
```

it works perfectly but the problem now is that I have the db but when I restart the app it will insert more data.

How do I check if the schema already exists dont do anything. **I just want to create the db if it doesn't have any tables / doesn't exist...**

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the property to update

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Create recreates it every time and update creates it only if it doesn't exist. The standard values can be seen here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html

- validate : validates the schema
- update : update if there are changes, create if it doesn't exist
- create : recreate it from scratch
- create-drop : creates it and then drops it when the session factory is closed

Also from the same reference we can see that import files are executed only if the hbm2ddl is create or create-drop

> File order matters, the statements of a give file are executed before
>   the statements of the following files. These statements are only
>   executed if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set
>   to create or create-drop.

If you want that **initial_sql** to be executed you can leave it as create and you can make that SQL to have the proper commands that don't change the state if already executed. Like `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` etc. For inserts it is a bit more complicated but you can still do it by `insert into table join the same table where value is not found`

That's not the perfect solution though because if you have tables created from annotated classes they will be recreated. I think you should think about another design or use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create when deploying for the first time and then changing it to update  manually

Comment: but if I switch to update it doesn't create the tables when I run the first time. this should be dynamic... I dont want to change the xml every time

Comment: basically if(schema doesn't exists) that option is create. else is update

Comment: Check what I wrote above. If it is update and you run it for the first time it will work as a create. Update is actually "create or update". Create is "drop and create"

Comment: I changed to update and it doesn't create any table so I assume `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/database/initial.sql</property>` is not running

Comment: Yeah if you want to use import_files they work only if you use create. So that's a bit of a problematic - if you use update it will recreate the database but only for annotated files. The import_files work only for create and create_drop but then they are executed every time. See the yellow box above. So you should either find another way to execute them or switch from create to update after deploy

Comment: Well I changed the dialect `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>` and it created the tables. **but it does not insert data into the table with my inserts on the script**

Comment: These files are executed only if you use CREATE but then it will recreate the database every time. See the answer above - the yellow part

Comment: that's why I said I needed a way to check if the schema exists so I can change the auto programatically. I dont see any other way

Comment: The problem with leaving it to create in order to get the initial_sql is that if you use anotations for tables it will recreate them every time! Even if you make your sql with "drop table if exists" and "create table if not exists"